OWL reasoner not recognizing negated restriction?
In following example (written in OWLready2):
    class A(Thing): pass
    class p(ObjectProperty, FunctionalProperty): pass
    class B(Thing): pass
    class B1(B): equivalent_to = [B & p.some(A)]
    class B2(B): equivalent_to = [B & Not(p.some(A))]

    b1 = B(p=A())
    b2 = B()

object b1 is reparented to B1, while b2 is not to B2. What's the reason for that? Did I use the wrong design pattern?

in OWL and any standard inference based on its formal semantics there holds the Open World Assumption. That means, absence of information doesn't mean the information isn't there somewhere else, it's just unknown (yet). Especially it doesn't lead to the negation or absence of some facts.

Aha. Thanks. I found OWLready2 has close_world() function which does the trick. It adds an p.only(Nothing) to the b2 individual (or B in case applied to the class). But seems to work only when property P is only meant for single class (A in this example) and not multiple.

Any suggestion how to do differentiation between B1 and B2 for a specific subclass of A?

What does b1 = B(p=A()) mean? p=A() seems to set the OWL object property p to be equal to the class A, which from OWL 2 perspective does not make sense at all. That is classes are sets of individuals and object properties are pairs of individuals. Moreover, from the OWL2ready paper this does not seem like intended syntax. Nor does the OWLReady2 docs refer to this syntax.

What b1 = B(p=A()) seems to mean is the following: p=A() creates an individual p of type A. The meaning of B(p) is that the class B is a subclass of the class represented by the single individual {p}.

If it is your objective to gain some understanding of OWL, I strongly recommend starting with a tool such as Protege and the Pizza tutorial.

It looks like you are confused by python syntax. B(p=A()) means I create an instance of class B with value A() (i.e. a newly created instance of class A) for its property p.

With respect to OWLReady docs: it has following example:
my_drug = Drug("my_drug2", namespace = onto, has_for_active_principle = [],...)
which is same syntax. (Except that I used FunctionalProperty which is singleton instead of list)

Because of Open World principle its considered unknown whether the defined individual b2 actually has a p=A().
OWLready2 has the means to use close world approach for the individual:
close_world(b2)

This will add a p.only(Nothing) restriction to b2, which is sufficient to infer b2 as being of class B2.
